# Adding days to a certain Calendar variable doesnt seem to work

Tags: java, calendar

Im doing a project about creating a hotel reservation system in java. I need help as I feel like my code is right(obviously isnt) but it doesnt seem to give me the right outcome.

So what I want to do is I have a 2 dates, one for check in and one for check out.
I ask the user for the checkin date which is fine and I set the check in date to the input. Then I ask for the number of nights he/her will be staying. By using the check-in date and number of nights I should be able to calculate the cost of the booking but when I add the days tot eh checkin date to get teh checkout date it sets the checkin date to the checkout date and calculates the cost from there.

Example: Checkin = thurs, number of nights = 2.

it sets the checkin date to saturday(thur + 2) and sets the checkout date to that too but calculates the cost of staying from sat to monday.

```
 String days [] = {"MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY",         "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"};
Calendar ci = r.getStartDate();
System.out.println("Original: " + ci.getTime());
Calendar co = ci;

for(int y = 0; y < nights; y++)
{
  co.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
  int dayOfWeek = co.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
  cost = cost + rates[dayOfWeek-1];
}

System.out.println("From: " + r.getStartDate().getTime());
System.out.println("Until: " + co.getTime());
r.setEndDate(co);
cost = cost - (cost*disc);
r.setCost(cost);
}
```

Output for Original is the correct date but is different for the from which is weird.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do rooms, hotels and reservations have to do with adding days to dates? Nothing whatsoever. Please strip down your question so it has only relevant content.

Comment: Stripped down hopefully its okay!

Comment: @Bohemian Stripped down!

Answer (score 0):

Your start and end dates are the same because your start and end Calendar objects are *the same* object:

```
Calendar ci = r.getStartDate();
Calendar co = ci;
```

Any modification you do to `co` is also modifying `r.getStartDate()` (and `ci` too, but you never use that variable).

I suspect you want to do this:

```
Calendar co = new Calendar();
co.setTime(r.getStartDate().getTime());
```

And delete the `ci` variable completely.